# Shell_exec of dynamically created script with else

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, cron, php

I am trying to use Shell_exec to a run a script which is dynamically created and stored in a php variable.  Here is the script so far.

```
{ curl -fsS --retry 3 https://hc-ping.com/same-unique-id-here ; \
echo "name.of.php.file.here STARTED for id # $state_id" ; \
php "/path/to/my.file.php" -i 2 -h prod 2>&1 | tee -a /path/to/log/files/my.file.log || \
curl -fsS --retry 3 https://hc-ping.com/same-unique-id-here/fail ; \
echo "name.of.php.file.here ENDED for id # $state_id with Exit Code $?" ; \
curl -fsS --retry 3 https://hc-ping.com/same-unique-id-here ; } 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &
```

My first problem is I only want to execute the last line

```
curl -fsS --retry 3 https://hc-ping.com/same-unique-id-here
```

if the

```
php "/path/to/my.file.php" -i 2 -h prod 2>&1 | tee -a /path/to/log/files/my.file.log
```

is successful.  How do I modify the script to do that?

My second question, is this how I print the exit code at the end of a echo?

```
echo "name.of.php.file.here ENDED for id # $state_id with Exit Code $?"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping for more interaction on this question.  I ended up using a variable to control what was executed.  Here is the code.

```
{ unset -v failcode ; failcode="0" ; curl -fsS --retry 3 https://hc-ping.com/same-unique-value ; \
echo "\n$(TZ="America/New_York" date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z") my.process.name.php STARTED for id # 2" ; \
php "/path/to/my/php/script.php" -i 2 -h lab || failcode="1" ; \
echo "\n$(TZ="America/New_York" date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z") my.process.name.php ENDED for id # 2 with Exit Code $failcode" ; \
[ "$failcode" == "1" ] && curl -fsS --retry 3 https://hc-ping.com/same-unique-value/fail ; \
[ "$failcode" == "1" ] && exit 1 ; \
curl -fsS --retry 3 https://hc-ping.com/same-unique-value ; } \
2>&1 | tee -a /path/to/my/log/file.log 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &
```